# Calculate average for each quarter given month columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a Python Pandas dataframe with 10 rows and 16 columns. Each row stands for one product. The first column is product ID. Other 15 columns are selling price for

> 2010/01,2010/02,2010/03,2010/05,2010/06,2010/07,2010/08,2010/10,2010/11,2010/12,2011/01,2011/02,2011/03,2011/04,2011/05.

(The column name is in strings, not in date format) Now I want to calculate the mean selling price each quarter (1Q2010,2Q2010,...,2Q2011), I don't know how to deal with it. (Note that there is missing month for 2010/04, 2010/09 and 2011/06.)

The description above is just an example. Because this data set is quite small. It is possible to loop manually. However, the real data set I work on is 10730*202. Therefore I can not manually check which month is actually missing or map quarters manually. I wonder what efficient way I can apply here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can convert string to datetime and apply a groupby query. I have not tried it. Its just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='M'), 'value': np.arange(72)})
df = rng.groupby([rng.date.dt.quarter, rng.date.dt.year]) .mean()
df.index.names = ['quarter', 'year']
df.columns = ['mean']
print df


             mean
quarter year      
1       2011     1
        2012    13
        2013    25
        2014    37
        2015    49
        2016    61
2       2011     4
        2012    16
        2013    28
        2014    40
        2015    52
        2016    64
3       2011     7
        2012    19
        2013    31
        2014    43
        2015    55
        2016    67
4       2011    10
        2012    22
        2013    34
        2014    46
        2015    58
        2016    70
```